# Finding minimum and maximum of 2-variable function in a closed area

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have this function: $f(x,y)=2x^3+3x^2y-3y$

I need to find the absolute minimum and maximum points that are within the triangle that is set by: $y=\frac{1}{3}x, x=1, y=0$

I started like this:

$$f_x(x,y) = 6x^2+6xy = 0$$
$$f_y(x,y) = 3x^2-3 = 0$$

Got the points: $(-1,1),(1,-1)$

But if we look at the intersection of all the lines that create the triangle, the points must be in $0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le \frac{1}{3}$

So how do I continue from here?

Thanks.

Comment: The partial derivates are not correct.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked here - https://www.symbolab.com/solver/partial-derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20x%7D%5Cleft(2x%5E%7B3%7D%2B3x%5E%7B2%7Dy-3y%5Cright)/?origin=enterkey
And it seems OK

Comment: so you missed one $y$ in the definition of $f$ ...

Comment: Yes I am sure. You wrote the partial derivatives of the function $f(x,y)=2x^3+3x^2y-3y$.

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco, sorry, my bad :| this is the correct function

Comment: @FigureItOut The discussion are essentially the same; the local minimum and maximum do not belong to the triangle; then the function needs to take maximum and minimun on the verteces.

Comment: So you would suggest to take the point $(0,\frac{1}{3})$ and $(1,0)$ ?

Comment: it does not suffice to look at the vertices. One also has to look at the sides of the triangle. (See my solution to the originally posted function.)

Comment: When you look for the extreme values of a function of a _single_ variable, you look for the critical points (with zero derivative) _within_ the interval, then check the endpoints of the closed interval.  The analogue for functions of _two_ variables is to check the "interior" of the two-dimensional region, then the "edges", and then the "vertices".  (Imagine the fun you'd have with three _or more_ variables!)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This is the solution for the originally posted function $f(x,y)=2x^3+3x^2y-3y$. But the principles are the same.

Looking at the partial derivatives shows that there is no local mininum or maximum inside the triangle.

Now let us look at the border, i.e. at the triangle sides and corners:

1. side $y=\frac{1}{3}x$: $f_1(x) = 2x^3+2x^2-x$, $f_1'(x) = 6x^2+4x-1 = 0$ has a root in $[0,1]$: $x_0 = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}-1}{3} = 0.19\ldots$, $f_1(x_0) = \frac{13-5 \sqrt{10}}{27} = -0.10\ldots$
2. side $x=1$: $f_2(y) = 4-3y$ has no local extremum
3. side $y=0$: $f_3(x) = 2x^3+2x^2$, $f_1'(x) = 6x^2+4x$ has roots at $x_1=0, x_2=\frac{2}{3}$, $f_3(x_1)=0, f_3(x_2)=\frac{40}{27}=1.48\ldots$
4. corner $(0,0)$: $f(0,0)=0$
5. corner $(1,0)$: $f(1,0)=4$
6. corner $(1,\frac{1}{3})$: $f(1,\frac{1}{3}) = 1$

So all together we have

- the minimum $f(x_0,\frac{1}{3}x_0) = f(0.19\ldots,0.06\ldots) = \frac{13-5\sqrt{10}}{27} = -0.10\ldots$ and
- the maximum $f(1,0)=4$.